# Tcp Client do not Disconnect

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, asynchronous, tcpclient

My problem is that first time i connect Tcp client to server using application Asynchronous 
it connect's and working but when i disconnect it and connect it again the data send two time like
s8
s8

Connection Code

---

```
                constatus.Text = "Connecting.....";
                //  newsock = null;
                newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                //IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 20);
                IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox2.Text), Convert.ToInt16(textBox3.Text));
                newsock.BeginConnect(iep, new AsyncCallback(Connected), newsock);
```

---

Data send code

---

```
            if (!InvokeRequired)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Allinput_Command);
                    client.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendData), client);
                 }
                catch (Exception) { }                   
            }
            else
            {
                Invoke(new ThreadStart(data_send));
            }
```

Disconnect Code

---

```
client.Close();
timer.Stop();
timer1.Stop();
```

---

please Tell me Right Path to solve this ....
i can send my all code if anybody tell me solution

Comment: To my memory... if you want to close the TCPClient, you have to call: newsock.EndConnect, try adding this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start coding anything that uses TCP, make sure you have a specification for the protocol you are layering on top of TCP. Otherwise, it is impossible to fix a bug like this. Once you have a specification, it's easy:

1. Is the sending program following the specification? If not, it's at fault.
2. Is the receiving program following the specification? If not, it's at fault.
3. If both programs follow the specification and communication still doesn't work, the specification is broken.

My bet is that you think you are sending messages but you are actually sending bytes. If you want to send messages, you need a specification that explains where messages begin and end, and both the sender and received must follow that specification.

Comment: Yes exactly i am sending data in form of Bytes David Schwartz can i send my code to you.